# Proving the Unit Sphere without the North Pole is Homeomorphic to the Plane

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble proving that the real plane and unit sphere with the north pole removed are homeomorphic. Even considering the function that maps from the sphere to the plane, I can't seem to show the function $(x,y,z) \rightarrow(\frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z})$ is continuous.

Comment: What have you tried so far? In particular, where have your attempts run into problems?

Comment: Just trying to do anything, really. Taking the distances between two points, I can't seem to come up with a viable delta epsilon proof.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is bounding the denominator, $(1-z)(1-z')$.

Comment: obviously there is no homeomorphism from $\mathbb{S}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ since $\mathbb{S}^2$ is compact while $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not compact.

Comment: Without the north pole.

Comment: without the pole yeah. this is what we are trying to show in here

Comment: Would you agree that your function is continuous on $\Bbb R^3$ (where it is defined?) If so, it's continuous when restricted to the punctured sphere.

Comment: @MikeMiller I was thinking that, but I haven't ever proved something continuous in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Phi(x,y,z)=(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z})$
$$\|\Phi(x,y,z)-\Phi(x',y',z')\|^2=\frac{x^2}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{x'^2}{(1-z')^2}-2\frac{xx'}{(1-z)(1-z')}$$
$$+\frac{y^2}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{y'^2}{(1-z')^2}-2\frac{yy'}{(1-z)(1-z')}$$
$$=\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{(x'^2+y'^2)}{(1-z')^2}-2\frac{xx'+yy'}{(1-z)(1-z')}=\frac{1+z}{1-z}+\frac{1+z'}{1-z'}-2\frac{xx'+yy'}{(1-z)(1-z')}$$
$$=\frac{2-2zz'-2(xx'+yy')}{(1-z)(1-z')}=\frac{[x(x-x')+y(y-y')+z(z-z')]+[x'(x'-x)+y'(y'-y)+z'(z'-z)]}{(1-z)(1-z')}$$
$$\frac{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}{(1-z)(1-z')}$$

So we have continuity as long we stay away from $N(0,0,1).$ However clearly as we approaching $N$,  $\|(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z})\|\to\infty$ (since numerators  of fractions stay bounded while denominators go to zero) and this is the whole point. Its called pole for the good reason.